# How can I postpone a fragment to a fragment transition like the activity transition (postponeEnterTransition

Tags: android, shared-element-transition, fragment-transitions

[How to postpone a Fragment's enter transition in Android Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977303/how-to-postpone-a-fragments-enter-transition-in-android-lollipop)

I have the troubles in the fragment transition. (shared element transition and so on.)
I want to make the fragment transition with screen orientation also well done.

After many trouble days, finally, I found out the below comments in the above link
But I don't understand it.

If you don't remove fragment1, but hide it instead, it will make your life easier. If not, an extra step is necessary, but it works in the same way.

- a) add 2, hide 2
- b) show 2, hide, add to back stack 1
- c) show 1, remove1, add to back stack. Then you detect that you have arrived at (c) the second time, you wait for 1 to be ready and then pop the back stack programmatically.

I don't understand above scenario. Please kindly explain this step by step.. Hope your answer.

Thanks in advance.