# Coming back for transition fragment shared element gone

Tags: android, fragment, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

In certain `View` in my app I'm displaying a `Fragment` with some `Omages` in a `RecyclerView`. When an `Image` is clicked, a new detail `Fragment` is shown (with an enter and return transition). The problem is when the Back `Button` is pressed from the details `View`, the shared element `View` sometimes is gone and sometimes not.

This is how I call the new details `Fragment`:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        dialog.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new DetailsTransition());
        dialog.setEnterTransition(new Slide());
        setExitTransition(new Fade());
        dialog.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new DetailsTransition());
    }

    dialog.setTargetFragment(this, DETAIL_FRAGMENT);

    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .addSharedElement(view, transitionmage)
            .replace(R.id.container, dialog, DetailFragment.TAG)
            .addToBackStack(DetailFragment.TAG)
            .commit();
```

I've already tried these solutions without success:

[How to postpone a Fragment's enter transition in Android Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977303/how-to-postpone-a-fragments-enter-transition-in-android-lollipop)

[Postponed Shared Element Transitions](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/03/activity-postponed-shared-element-transitions-part3b.html)

Comment: Can you post a simple project in github?

Comment: did you find a solution?