# Android Fragments transition issue

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, animation, fragment

When transitioning from one fragment HelloAfragment to HelloBfragment using below code,     how to add a delay when transitioning from HelloAfragment to HelloBfragment

```
   TAG = HelloFrament.class.getSimpleName();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
           .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right)
            .replace(HelloAfragment.getId(), HelloBfragment, TAG)
            .addToBackStack(TAG)
            .commit();
```

Comment: change android:duration="700" in slide_in_left.xml

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26984314/3496570

Comment: @mohitSuthar I did add duration on the slide_in_left.xml but dint work

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
            fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, firstFragment, "h");
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("h");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Use this code for animation given by android studio..            `fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);`

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a small change, Use below code in slide_in_left

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
       android:fromXDelta="1000" android:toXDelta="0"
       android:duration="700"/>
```

and this Code for slide_in_right

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-1000"
       android:duration="700"/>
```

Comment: I tried all and finally ended up using an activity instead of fragment

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to achieve transition between two fragment's, so I ended up changing the destination fragment to activity and used the below code for activity

```
       View imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    View textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    View button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EndActivity.class);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        textView.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.activity_text_trans));
        button.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.activity_mixed_trans));

        Pair<View, String> pair1 = Pair.create(imageView, imageView.getTransitionName());
        Pair<View, String> pair2 = Pair.create(textView, textView.getTransitionName());
        Pair<View, String> pair3 = Pair.create(button, button.getTransitionName());
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, pair1, pair2, pair3);
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }
    else {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```